# In HTML5 are the class, id and xml:lang attributes values case-insensitive or case-sensitive?

Tags: html

I keep reading that in HTML5 the `class`, `id` and `xml:lang` attributes values are `case-insensitive` and then i read other tutorials and books that say they are `case-sensitive`. So what is it can some one help me figure this out.

One book gave me an example stating that the class attributes value is case-insensitive, e.g. the `<span class="a">...</span>` is different from `<span class="A">...</span>`.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping all tag and attribute names in lower-case will always work,  but HTML5 is case-insensitive.

Comment: So is the case-insensitive, e.g. the `<span class="a">...</span>` is different from `<span class="A">...</span>` Correct?

Comment: The values are still case-sensitve. e.g., if I use JS to get the value of the attribute, it will return `a` or `A`, whichever is in the HTML. But `CLASS="a"` is the same as `class="a"`.

Comment: So the example the book provided was wrong they are case-sensitive and not case-insensiive?

Comment: Case-insensitive means that it doesn't matter if it's in upper-case or lower-case. I've never used upper-case for tag or attribute names, but I haven't seen any problems from using upper-case.